# vim map q to 0 in the .vimrc has unexpected behaviour

Tags: vim

I am attempting to remap my 0 key to q to quickly return to the beginning of the current line in my .vimrc file.

I have:
`map q 0`

Expected Behavior:
Upon pressing q in normal mode the cursor should move to the zeroth column position on the current line.

Current Behavior:
Upon pressing q in normal mode the cursor moves the the 1st column on the current line.

Not sure what the reason is for this behavior. Thanks in advance :)

Versions:
VIM - Vi IMproved: 8.1,
Iterm2: Build 3.3.7,
MacOS: 10.13.4

Comment: do you have a `.vimrc`? When I type that command, I don't have any problems using `q` to go to the zeroth column in normal mode.

Comment: What does `:nmap q` print? Is there a `<Space>` at the end?

Comment: Dont do it! It’s not worth it! `0` is easy to type, you often need `I` anyway, and `q` for recording macros is too useful. (Also, you should really read about `:nnoremap` and why you should prefer specific variants over generic `:map`). Don’t do this!

Answer (score 2):

There was a trailing space on the command in my .vimrc file. Thanks for your help everyone. I hadn't realized a trailing space would be picked up like that. Good to know for future reference.